# Where to ask about Radio Controlled (RC) modelling in general?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a place to ask general questions about RC (radio controlled) modelling or do I need to target the questions to various dedicated sites (engineering, electronics etc.)?

Topics in question are things like building, operation and maintenance of RC models.

Comment: You're more than welcome to follow the [RC site proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97520/radio-controlled). Other than that, I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: @Catija I see the proposal was removed - what a pitty! I always get upset when proposals I like die (because of lack of community interest or whatever)...

Comment: Keep in mind that stack exchange sites are reserved only for questions specific enough to have specific answers.  Many radio control questions and curiosities are better handled on traditional forum sites, and there are some *huge* ones for RC.  A few RC topics are technically specific enough to fit on some stack exchange sites, but please be careful of the rules and topic, for example questions  about *using* modular RC products like ESC's or flight control boards are off topic on electronics SE, which is only for *electronic design* questions.